# Java program execution thread

Tags: java

When the java program execution starts from controller to all the way till DAO layer, In between i want to halt the execution until some heavy lifting operation happens at some other model(Post request to do some operation). and then resume the task in my current model.

Can we halt the current process execution for sometime and then resume the process in java?

Comment: Don't use `sleep`. Read about the `wait-notify` approach.

Comment: You can use wait-notify, semaphores, `Future` (especially if that heavy op is in background) count down latches etc.

Comment: what are the heavy operations? Please add those details as well.

Comment: @BilboBaggins Retrieving the current status of the inventory with RFC

Comment: I assume it is going to be a DB call? or an microservice call?

Answer (score 3):

IMO you can make use of `CompletableFuture` where you want to execute some other operation and wait for it to be completed as shown below:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Call the function");    
future.get();
```

Now `future.get()`is used to retrieve the result of computation so it will block till the o/p is not available and once it is then will proceed.